# sails warnings --minUptime not set

Tags: javascript, sails.js

my sails applications tells me this warnings:

```
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
```

where do I have to set this ?

Maybe set in package.json?

```
{
  "name": "HoloDive",
  "version": "1.2.1",
  "description": "Comfortable maintenance for Holacracy-based organizations.",
  "author": "Michael Walz <michaelwalz.dev@gmail.com>",
  "private": true,
  "keywords": [
    "holacracy",
    "organization",
    "governance"
  ],
  "bugs": {
    "email": "michaelwalz.dev@gmail.com"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "sails lift --prod",
    "debug": "node debug app.js",
    "test": "grunt test"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=6.11.1",
    "npm": ">=3.10.10"
  },
```

Comment: no I dont use forever

Comment: I rechecked it I use forever ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are likely Command Line Arguments, which you need to pass to your app when starting it from a *SH Console.

Instead of just writing

```
$ sails yourApp
```

Try the command with the arguments set

```
$ sails --minUptime 1000 --spinSleepTime 1000 yourApp
```

Comment: for what is spinSleepTime?

Comment: when I run your command I got this:  `fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.`

Comment: `--spinSleepTime  Time to wait (millis) between launches of a spinning script.`

Comment: is there a ways to set this in a config?

Comment: Hm, I don't think so

Comment: I updated my question, maybe in the start command in `package.json`?

Comment: Oh, sure, you can add those there!

Comment: Nothing changed same issue. I use forever, ... Any hints for me? thanks

Comment: You can also just ignore these, warnings are not errors

Comment: issue is that if the application is running several hours without accessing it the application is down. I got errors that assets are missing or the websocket connection has gone lost. 

Then I have to reboot the whole docker container